# Why is my MySQL cascade deletion not working?

Tags: mysql, database, cascade

I have three tables: Employee, Dependent, and DependsOn. For some reason, on my server, the MySQL code isn't doing the cascade deletions correctly. I insert an Employee, a Dependent, then link them in DependsOn. If I delete the Employee, it should delete the corresponding row in DependsOn. However, this is not the case. If I run the query in SQLFiddle.com, it works fine. Why is this not working?

```
CREATE TABLE Employee 
( 
  SSN int(9) not null unique, 
  First_Name varchar(16) default null, 
  Middle_Initial char(1) default null, 
  Last_Name varchar(16) default null, 
  Address varchar(64) default null, 
  Phone_Number char(10) default null, 

  PRIMARY KEY(SSN) 
);

CREATE TABLE Dependent
(
  Dependent_Name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  Dependent_Relationship varchar(32) NOT NULL,

  KEY(Dependent_Name),
  KEY(Dependent_Relationship)
);

CREATE TABLE DependsOn
(
  E_SSN int(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  D_Name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  D_Relationship varchar(32) NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY(E_SSN) REFERENCES Employee(SSN) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(D_Name) REFERENCES Dependent(Dependent_Name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(D_Relationship) REFERENCES Dependent(Dependent_Relationship) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(111223333, "John", "A", "Doe", NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO Dependent VALUES("Albert A Doe", "Son");
INSERT INTO DependsOn(111223333, "Albert A Doe", "Son");
```

Comment: Are your tables using the InnoDB or MyISAM engine? MyISAM does not support foreign keys (outside of ignoring them and not breaking when the are present in the CREATE statement).

Comment: @Uueerdo They were using the MyISAM engine. I just altered the tables (changed the engine for all three, inserted and deleted) to see if that would fix it to no avail.

Comment: Did you just `ALTER` the tables or `DROP` and re`CREATE` them? I don't know if just altering will actually add the foreign key constraints that were ignored when the table was created as MyISAM.

Comment: Oh my god, that was it! I had to recreate them and specify the engine. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, I've posted an answer summarizing the stuff we worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MyISAM storage engine permits FOREIGN KEY constraint definitions in CREATE statements, but ignores them. Changing the table engine, to one that supports such constraints such as InnoDB, after the table has already been created does not retroactively add the constraints. The table must be either dropped and re-created, or to preserve the data, the constraints themselves can be added.